# Implicit declaration of function in C

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Is there any version of C, or any compiler that does not allow implicit declaration of functions?

For example. Using mingw compiler, if I use the printf function within my program without including stdio.h, it compiles my program, displaying a warning "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'".

i would like to know if there is some version of C, or some compiler, which does not compile my program in these situations.

Best regards.

Comment: Why not look at the various options available to the various compilers? Most allow you to make the warnings as errors

Comment: Use `-Werror` and the code won't compile.

Comment: The 1999 standard did away with implicit `int`, so compiling with `-std=c99 -Werror` should catch any implicit declarations.

Comment: This is interesting. However, I am still interested in the original question.

Is there any compiler that, in its standard operation, does not compile a program with implicit declaration?

Comment: The compiler has already issued a diagnostic for you. Ignoring this diagnostic means the program will have undefined behavior. Warnings should be treated as errors unless you never plan to change compilers or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: Should have been done away with in the 1979 standard.  'Hmm.. no declaration, so I'll make something up'.  Great, nice one Ritchie.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling use `-Werror` option and all warnings will be considered errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Werror` compiler option while compiling your code. It will consider all warning as `error`. I like to compile my source code using these option.

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wshadow -Wextra SOURCE.c -Wfloat-equal
```